# Pointers and references obtained from a forward iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator) states in the `std::forward_iterator` semantic requirements that:

> - Pointers and references obtained from a forward iterator into a range remain valid while the range exists.

What exactly does this mean? What if I obtain a pointer from a range's iterator, then execute some iterator-invalidating action on this range? The iterator might be invalidated and the underlying pointer/reference as well. Or am I misunderstanding some terms?